# using of Custom Tabs with StackNavigator?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have list of users , each user has  its display image in the list.

What I am trying is whenever user presses the display image , get redirected to his/her profile through stackNavigation .

**CustomTabView:**

```
    const CustomTabView = ({ router, navigation }) => {
  const { routes, index } = navigation.state;

  const ActiveScreen = router.getComponentForState(navigation.state);

  const routeNav = addNavigationHelpers({
    ...navigation,
    state: routes[index],
  });
  const routeOptions = router.getScreenOptions(routeNav, 'tabBar');
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <CustomTabBar
        navigation={navigation}
        activeRouteName={routes[index].routeName}
        icon={routeOptions.tabBarIcon}
      />
      <ActiveScreen
        navigation={addNavigationHelpers({
          ...navigation,
          state: routes[index]
        })}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

**StackNavigator:** // goToProfile.js // also tried placing in index.anndroid.js but didnt found a way to export

```
const goToProfile = StackNavigator({
  Profile: {
    screen: Profile,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: `${navigation.state.params.person.name.first} ${navigation.state.params.person.name.last}`
    })
  },
})
```

**custom tabs:** //index.android.js

```
const CustomTabRouter = TabRouter(
  {
    Chat: {
      screen: Chats,
      path: ""
    },
    Status: {
      screen: Contacts,
      path: "notifications"
    },
    Camera: {
      screen: Camera,
      path: "settings"
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Chat",
  },


     );

    const CustomTabs = createNavigationContainer(
     createNavigator(CustomTabRouter)(CustomTabView)
    );
```

**Also my component :**

```
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress = { () =>  this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile', { item } ) }  >
              <Avatar
                source={{ uri: item.picture.thumbnail }}
              />
          </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: @Cruiser how do I use stacknavigator in my chats screen to achieve that

Comment: SO isn't a code-writing service. I suggest you make an attempt and ask a question when you're stuck, get an error, or otherwise run into problems

Comment: @Cruiser haha, I kno , I've tried different methods, didn't worked out

Comment: @Cruiser i've tried to use stacknavigator const to include in chats screen as `chats { screen: goToProfile } `

Comment: but i don't think that's relevant

Comment: @Cruiser edited

Comment: You will have to restructure your stack navigator and your tab navigator, so that your tab navigator will accommodate  your stack navigator

Comment: @CalebToluIsrael any hint You would like to give?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Your Stack Navigator will look like this:**

```
    const ChatStack= StackNavigator({
      Chat:{screen: Chat,
      navigationOptions: {
       header: null,
     }},
     Profile: {
        screen: Profile,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
          title: `${navigation.state.params.person.name.first} ${navigation.state.params.person.name.last}`,
          tabBarVisible: false
         // depending if you want to hide the tabBar on the profile page if not remove it.
        })
      },
    })
```

**Then Your customTab will take this shape:**

```
const CustomTabRouter = TabRouter(
  {
    Chat: {
      screen: ChatStack,
    },
    Status: {
      screen: Contacts,
      path: "notifications"
    },
    Camera: {
      screen: Camera,
      path: "settings"
    }
  },
.........
```

With those changes you should be able to navigate to Profile screen with your

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile', { item } )
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to dispatch a navigation action, not render a new stack - Although I'm not sure your navigators are properly constructed for this to succeed...

```
_goToProfile = (person) => {
  <goToProfile navigate={this.props.navigation} />
}
```

should be

```
_goToProfile = (person) => {
  this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile', person)
}
```

Comment: already tried that... screen profile isnot defined in top level component so it doesnt works

Comment: Correct, your example code doesn't contain enough information for me to provide a full answer.  

Would be handy to see all your Navigators.

If you change `screen: Profile,` to `screen: CustomTabs` does that work?

Comment: nope that doesnt worked ...CustomTabs was not considered as screen :(